# Inserir ícone no input text com HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, front-end, webdesign

Olá eu gostaria de inserir um ícone no input text do meu sistema, até consegui colocar o ícone, mas quando clico no input para digitar o texto o ícone simplesmente nao oculta. podem me ajudar?

[image: código fonte]

[image: O lance era oculta o icone buscar quando clico no input.]

Comment: Tente usar algo como: <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você der foco no seu campo text:

você usa a pseudo class `:focus` para remover o `background-image` do seu `input`

Declare no seu css:

```
input[type='text']:focus { 
    background-image: none; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, deu certo amigo.

Comment: Boa! se resolveu .. marca como resposta. Abraço!

Comment: Não sei como faz é a primeira vez que estou usando..rs

Answer (score 0):

Algo como:

```
<i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
<input type="text" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" onclose="fechaTeclado();" />
```

Onde o `<i>` você coloca o ícone que deseja.

Comment: Obrigadoa amigo pela ajuda.

Comment: Obrigadoa amigo pela ajuda.